# Hosting spring boot app

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I could not host my spring boot app to Amazon Web Services: Elastic Beanstalk. I did follow some video tutorials and stack overflow posts. still helpless. I want to host my war file to AWS and run it successfully. Here is my pom.xml and other stuff. it works well in the local. but after deploying to aws it does not work. the health status shown is severe.

[**Error Page Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pGWW.png)

**`POM.XML`**

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cloudsofts.cloudschool</groupId>
    <artifactId>CloudSchool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Cloud School</name>
    <description>School Management Software</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url-base=jdbc:mysql://cloudschool.cw86hx95lpfe.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
spring.datasource.url=${spring.datasource.url-base}/cloud_school

spring.datasource.username=[username]
spring.datasource.password=[password]
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=1

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl: DEBUG  
logging.level.org.hibernate.type: TRACE 

server.port:80

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true 
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=cloud_school.sql


logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE


googleAppscript.translate.url = https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxu0351TyszGL6fAU9KHVYeR7jsaUMkm6v5fUCfI9eu_kFgLRgA/exec
```

**Main Class**

```
package com.cloudsofts.cloudschool;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class CloudSchoolStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(CloudSchoolStarter.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**Beanstalk log**

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/localhost.2018-03-27.log
-------------------------------------
27-Mar-2018 12:21:36.066 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
27-Mar-2018 12:21:47.458 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext


-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
-------------------------------------
172.31.27.16 (172.31.27.16) - - [27/Mar/2018:12:23:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
172.31.91.28 (172.31.91.28) - - [27/Mar/2018:12:23:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
172.31.27.16 (172.31.27.16) - - [27/Mar/2018:12:23:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.2018-03-27.log
-------------------------------------
27-Mar-2018 12:21:29.021 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/classes/com/cloudsofts/cloudschool] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
27-Mar-2018 12:21:29.025 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/classes/com/cloudsofts/cloudschool/translate] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache


org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1129)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1871)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/cloudsofts/cloudschool/multitenant/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getValidationMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:88)
```

**New Error**

```
------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2018/03/27 15:41:56 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:41:56 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:05 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:06 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:15 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:16 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:25 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:26 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:35 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:36 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:45 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:46 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:55 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:42:56 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:43:05 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:43:06 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:43:15 [error] 29286#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.29.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
2018/03/27 15:43:16 [error] 29286#0: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.2.252"
```

Comment: You should at least describe the problems / errors you encounter.

Comment: Stop. mixing versions. You are mixing jars from spring boot 1.5.2 and 1.5.9 never mix versions of a framework. Also remove the `persistence-api` dependency that is already included in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and what you include is an ancient version not compatible with the hibernate version you are getting through `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

Comment: @M.Deinum That should be an answer.

Comment: I updated the pom.xml and built a new jar. still I am getting the same error. what may be the cause?

Comment: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong in your `pom.xml`

1. mixing version of Spring Boot 1.5.2 and 1.5.9 (never mix versions of a framework).
2. Inclusion JPA 1.0 API whereas you use a JPA 2.0 provider
3. Generally AWS BeanStalk want your app to run on port 5000.

For 1 remove the `<version>` tag in your conflicting dependency and/or change the version of Spring Boot to the matching version.

Remove the JPA 1.0 API.

AWS expects your application to run on port 5000. Either specify this in the `application.properties` to be the port or specify a environment variable `SERVER_PORT` with value `5000` in your AWS environment. See [Deploying a Spring Boot Application on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) and especially the section on how to specify the port.